# Name validation no space

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do a validation including these requires:

- Allow to insert a name with space between , example: "Nicolas Tesla"
- Not allow to insert spaces or numbers , example: "  " or "12354"

I have this function but i don't know if i'm doing right:

```
function ValidName(){
    var regex = /^[a-zA-Z]$/;
    var name = $("#txtNome").val();

    if(name == ""){
        alert("Please, type your name.");
        name.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if(name =! name.regex){
        alert("Please, type your name.");
        name.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

The first "if" is working , if i don't type anything then alert comes out , but the second one isn't and i don't know if i'm doing right , in fact i don't know what i'ma doing.

Comment: So, there must be at least one alphabet in your name? can you share some sample success and failure scenarios?

Comment: How about `Gómez Núñez`? It this a valid name?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, modify your regex so that it accepts strings with at least one character separated with one space with another set of one or more characters:

```
var regex = /^[a-zA-Z]+(\s[a-zA-Z]+)?$/;
```

That will save you the first "if" statement.

Then, to check if your regex match, you should use [RegExp.prototype.test](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/RegExp/test)

your code would then look like

```
function ValidName(){
    var regex = /^[a-zA-Z]+(\s[a-zA-Z]+)?$/;
    var $name = $("#txtNome");

    if(!regex.test($name.val())){
        alert("Please, type your name.");
        $name.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: i did and even with this he keeps to accept empty spaces when i insert.

Comment: @PauloRobertoLS just tested it and it does not accepts empty spaces with my regex. Your problem must be somewhere else

Comment: note that I modified your code a bit because you were trying to call `.focus` on `$("#txtNome").val()` which does not make sense